# getting objects nested in an absolutely positioned element to not wrap/clear/stack

Tags: css, css-position

I have a tooltip menu that I'm trying to get sorted out. My issue that I can't seem to keep my links in the menu from wrapping to a new line. What I've tried so far is `display:inline` `float:left` on the links in the child element, and `white-space:nowrap` on the child element itself. These tricks aren't working. I'm hoping that someone can help me out.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SW7hj/2/

Things I can't/don't want to do:

- insert a `width:400px` or whatever into the child element tag (The links inside the child element will change regularly)
- remove the `right:100%` positioning on the child element (that's where I need it to show up)
- give up and go home (paid job, ya see.)

Comment: So you want the links next to each other horizontally? Remove `float:left` from `#son-box a`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SW7hj/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float:left` from `#son-box a`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SW7hj/3/

Comment: I'm amazed that this alluded me, but thank you so much! I thought I was going mad!